# How do I test a class using JUnit 4 that extends an abstract class?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, jmockit

I am trying to write a unit test for a java class that is extending an abstract class? The java class looks sort of like:

```
public class XYZFilter extends XYZDataFilter{

   @Override
   protected boolean filterItem(Model d, String sector) {

    //method code
    return true;    
   }
}
```

The junit test class looks like:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class XYZFilterTest {
Model m = new Model();
String sector = "SECTOR";

@Test
public void testFilterItem() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("\nTest filterItem method...");
    XYZFilter f = new XYZFilter();
    assertTrue(f.filterItem(m, sector));
}
}
```

So I'm having a problem with the abstract DataFilter which is extended by the Filter class, as well as the Model class. I believe I need to mock these objects using JMockit but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do this. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: jUnit is just pure Java. The method `filterItem()` in class `Filter` will be called. What is your real problem? As far as I see it, your test will succeed.

Comment: I changed the name of the class for business reasons forgetting Filter is part of the Java API. It's actually more like XZYFilter, I'll modify the original example.

Comment: That's not what I meant though. The class you show here will be called, what is your problem?

Comment: my problem basically is Im trying to write a junit test for a class that extends an abstract class which isn't available, so it won't compile because it can't see the extended class. There is a method in the class I'm testing that uses a protected method in this abstract class. So without having this class I'm getting unresolved object/method errors when compiling because it can't see them. I want to use JMockit to mock this class and method as well as the Model class which is outside the scope of my test package.

Comment: Well, it needs to compile if you are to test it, right? Extending a class that isn't available doesn't make sense. Make sure it is available on the classpath.

Comment: I thought that was the point of JMoockit, to remove overhead and be able to test a single unit/class independent of other classes?

Comment: You were wrong. To test classes, classes must exist, and must thus have been compiled. Mocking framework don't transform non-compilable Java source code into runnable classes.

Comment: in particular, any class you want to reference needs to have every class in its hierarchy resolvable both at compile time and runtime.  Besides, the point of mocking is usually (almost exclusively) for mocking collaborators.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is I needed to have the libraries included, JMockit doesn't handle objects in that way.